# Powershell: matching multi-line text

Tags: regex, powershell

With **Powershell** I need to **check if the WinRM HTTP listener is already enabled**, so I'm trying to **multi-line match the output** of `winrm e winrm/config/listener`:

```
$listeners = winrm e winrm/config/listener

$regex = @'
(?ms)(Transport = HTTPS)
'@

$listeners -match $regex > $null
$matches[1]
```

`$listeners` has the correct output:

```
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = [certificate thumbprint]
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 123.123.123.123, ::1
```

But unfortunately, `matches` is an empty array:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\me\Documents\PowerShellTest.ps1:8 char:1
+ $matches[1]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved in another way:

```
$listeners = winrm e winrm/config/listener
$regex = '(?s)(^\s+Transport = HTTPS$)' 
$listeners | Select-String $regex -AllMatches | Select -Expand Matches | select -expand Value
```

Now it works:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents> .\PowerShellTest.ps1
Transport = HTTPS
```

Comment: If you want to catch HTTP aswell, add a questionmark here: `$regex = '(?s)(^\s+Transport = HTTPS?$)' `